# How can I calculate R1, R2, RC and RE in the following silicon transistor circuit?

Tags: transistors, biasing

[image: the givens are in the image]

We have 4 unknowns, so we need 4 equations.

If we make the equivalent Thévenin circuit for R1 and R2, and by applying KVL on the input and outputs we get only 2 equations.

[image]

Rth=(R1×R2)/(R1+R1)
Vth=(Vcc×R2)(R1+R2)

First equation from KVL on input:

EQ1: Vth-IB×Rth-VBE-IE=0

Second equation from KVL on output:

EQ2: Vcc-ICQ×Rc-VCE-IE×RE=0

We substitute IB=ICQ/β , IE=((β+1)/β)IC so IE approximately equals ICQ.
So EQ1: Vth-(5×10<sup>-3</sup>)/(100)Rth-0.7-5×10<sup>-3</sup>=0

EQ2: 12-(5×10<sup>-3</sup>)×RC+6-(5×10<sup>-3</sup>)×RE=0

And then:

EQ1: Vth-(5×10<sup>-5</sup>)Rth-0.695=0

EQ2: 18-(5×10<sup>-3</sup>)×RC-(5×10<sup>-3</sup>)×RE=0

How can I get the solution of this problem?

Comment: you'll have to tell us which equations you're using – there's more than one mathematical model for the NPN transistor, but even if we inferred you'd be using a specific model, we would not know where you're stuck. So please, write down your approach as for as you've gotten.

Comment: Is VCBQ labeled correctly? Should it be VCEQ?

Comment: VCBQ is giving the value of VCE. VCE=-VCBQ=-6V

Comment: Does the problem give you any other guidance?  There's two free parameters as it it stated -- in a normal design problem you'd choose the standing value of \$\mathrm{V_C}\$ and the bias network impedance to be sensible values -- but at this level of class, you don't have the background to know what "sensible" is.

Comment: @Issasafar You need to include two decisions. Without source and load specs, schematic standing in isolation like this, this is the stiffness of the voltage divider and one of these two: (a) the emitter voltage which directly impacts temperature stability or (b) the voltage gain magnitude. The rest can be done from there. But you need two additional specifications. Tim is correct about two free parameters, but they don't have to be the two he specified. But two are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If we make equivalent Thevinin ... only 2 equations.

There is not sufficient information in the problem, as stated, to calculate all four resistor values.  As you've stated it, you have **four** unknowns and **two** constraints.  Either the question gives you the information somewhere else, it's buried in assumptions from the class, or you simply cannot get there from here.

With the problem as stated, you are free to trade off the values of RE and RC, establishing \$\mathrm{V_E}\$ as you see fit.  For \$\beta = \infty\$, their sum would be constant but their difference would be a free parameter of your choosing.

Similarly, once you choose RE, \$\mathrm{V_{th}}\$ and \$\mathrm{R_{th}}\$ are interdependent, and you can choose *one* of these.

So -- two equations, two unknowns, and two free parameters.

Comment: Can you expalin i didn't get it clear, how you calculated Ve ?

Comment: I want to calculate the values of R1 R2 RE and Rc by calculations depending on the givens please give me methods and equations for the solution.

Comment: I never did calculate \$\mathrm{V_E}\$.  Because it's a free parameter, so it cannot be _calculated_, just set as your heart desires.  "I want to calculate the values of..."  I have edited my answer to stress the fact that you cannot do so from the given information.

Comment: I know there is a solution because this question was a part of exam maybe the givens are insufficient as you stated. If i get the solution from the lecturer i will anwer my question. Thanks for your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is straightforward (no Thévenin transformations necessary):

- Because the current Ic and both voltages Vcc and Vce are given, the resistor values for Rc and Re can be selected with Ic(Re+Rc)=Vcc-Vce (common practice: Re app 0.1*Rc)
- Setting Vbe to app. 0.7 volts you can calculate the required base voltage Vb (against ground).
- Now you are free to select the impedance niveau for the voltage divider R1, R2 for producing Vb. (Remember that Ic=f(Vbe), the base current Ib is only a kind of by-product).
- If you have some information about the factor B=Ic/Ib you can use Ib (through R1) for selecting proper values for the resistors R1 and R2.
- In any case, you should use resistor values which allow a current through the divider which is at least 10 times larger than the expected base current Ib. In this case, we say that the voltage divider produces a sufficiently "stiff" voltage Vb (only a rather small influence of Ib uncertainties).
- If you are unsure because the "vague" assumption of Vbe=0.7 volts, remember that Re creates sufficient voltage feedback which makes the whole circuit relatively unsensitive to the (unknown, estimated) transitor parameters.

Comment: The factor is given Ic/Ib=100

Comment: Do you know the voltage drop across Rc? I suppose, Vce is given with 6V. This should be enough....

Comment: "Ic(Re+Rc)=Vcc-Vce" how you calculated Re and Rc if the are unknowns. You can if you  substitute one resistor interms of another ,So how that could be?

Comment: As I have written: It depends on the desired gain (you know the formula?). Otherwise, it is common practice to choose  Rc=10Re (approximately). That means: Good DC stabilization. When the AC gain is too low (due to signal feedback), you can bypass Re (or a part of it) with a capacitor.

Comment: I am okay with you , in real life you can assume things depending on what you design circuit for. Anyway, can i solve it without assuming Rc=10Re?, i don't  care about AC stuffs because i need the DC analysis.

Comment: You cannot "solve" for all parts values within the design procedure - in particular when you have no requirements for gain and input/output resistances. You should accept (and be happy) that you have the freedom to choose some parts values and/or ratios.

Comment: Ok thanks for helping.