# CE Amplifier problem

Tags: amplifier, speakers, common-emitter, biasing, capacitive-coupling

I am new to learning about electricity and I was trying to make a common emitter amplifier.

I did some research and I tried to make the circuit. The circuit amplified the signal but the signal was not clear and was cutting out. The signal I am trying to amplify is audio from an iPad headphone jack. The circuit diagram is below.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix this? Thanks.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhySYg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Vcc = 9 V)

Comment: Because the capacitor bypass R3, the gain is R3/re which is very high and may cause clipping. You can remove C3 or split R4 into 2 resistors and bypass one.

Comment: R3/Re. what is re?

Comment: @MarcusMarchese your schematic contains a resistor labeled "Re"

Comment: @MarcusMarchese I get where the input is coming from -- a headphone jack designed to drive a headphone. But what are you listening to? Is this some speaker you have? Or what, exactly? Details matter.

Comment: It is a youtube video from the Ipad that I plug the cable into and I am trying to amplify that signal. I have the amplifier connected to a 1 watt speaker

Comment: @MarcusMarchese 1 watt speaker tells me something. But what's the nameplated Ohms for the speaker?

Comment: @MarcusMarchese You will need a 2-quadrant driver for the speaker, I believe. That's either going to be class-A or class-AB. That is also going to be 2 transistors, at minimum, just for that part. You will need negative feedback (NFB), as well. And then my own preference would be two more BJTs. But technically, you can get away with just one more and find a way for NFB. So that could be done, I think. Maybe 3 BJTs. No less. Maybe more. But not ***one*** BJT. Sorry. That's not going to drive a 1 watt speaker for you. So what are you looking for? Construction article? Or learn to design it?

Comment: @Marcus M. Perhaps the following link (former discussion in this forum) may help:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/650224/how-can-i-calculate-r1-r2-rc-and-re-in-the-following-silicon-transistor-circui

Comment: @periblepsis I would like a website that would be able to teach me how to design these amplifiers. I am trying to learn electronics for a fun hobby. Thanks for your response

Comment: @LvW that former discussion helps. Thank you

Comment: @MarcusMarchese This isn't much of a site to *teach*. Unfortunately. But it is a fact of this place. That said, I get you and appreciate your desires. You have a lot to gather up, yet. You need to accept that fact. When I write *"2-quadrant"* you will need to follow that idea. But to follow it, you need some other parts to get there. This is a *"one step at a time"* kind of thing. So you need to embrace the idea that there a few different ideas to absorb, first: NFB, 2-quadrant, etc. Once you get those, you will find an easier path ahead. But you need to assimilate these ideas, first.

Comment: @MarcusMarchese So, perhaps the first thing to absorb is the idea of *2-quadrant*. This just means, in short, something that can actively drive high as well as drive low, with low impedance in both directions. And just that idea is already another problem, because what do I mean when I say *"actively drive low"* and/or *"actively drive high"*?? Why and what exactly does that mean??? So there is much to discuss and much to absorb. And that is only one of several steps along the way. Here we are only talking about the part of the circuit that must drive the speaker, itself.

Comment: @MarcusMarchese So to ***"teach me how to design these amplifiers"*** involves a lot of work. Foundations need to be laid down. Etc. Once you possess these, then the rest will just flow out from there. And yes, it's not all that difficult. But you need to acquire and hold some ideas in your head to guide your thinking. And this generally means tearing down other ideas you hold dear at this point so that you can make room for other ideas, more important ones, that will allow you to think more correctly about the problems ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The beginning

I added some elements (input source, load and power supply) necessary to bring your circuit to life in CircuitLab...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK6tgg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

... and I saw it working.

[image: STEP 0]

After you expressed your desire to understand the ideas in this famous circuit (which rarely happens here), I decided to write this amazing story on Christmas Eve as an alternative to boring textbook explanations. This is how I want to show that handling circuits is not only a craft but can also be an art.

## How we understand circuits

It would be great if we could get ready knowledge directly from some very reputable sources. If so, I would now answer you with only a few paragraphs of concise laconic text taken from such sources and repeatedly relayed. However, Nature has decided that we should do it in a more difficult way - slowly and painfully, making mistakes and learning from our experience.

To  really understand a circuit, you need to know not only what and how it was done, but also why it was done. The best way to do it practically is to start from the very beginning, building the circuit step-by-step and exploring it at each step. Here is a possible scenario for making such an amplifier.

## What an amplification is

There is no such thing as *power amplification* in the literal sense of the word;  rather it is *power regulation* (control). This is not proven, it is a postulate. In such an "amplifier", a low power source controls a high power source, and this creates the illusion of power amplification. Let's see the possible ways in which we can make an amplifier following this recipe.

## Building an amplifier

### Controlled source

If we could control the (output) voltage of the power source by another smaller (input) voltage, it would be the simplest amplifier. In the simulation below, I (like the input voltage) have imitated it by sweeping the supply voltage Vs from 0 to 10 V. Run *DC Sweep Simulation* to see it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4UJfM.png)</sup>

[image: STEP 1]

### Controlled load

**Voltage-supplied load:** If we could control the load resistance, it would be an even more exotic "amplifier" (so, for example, by switching the heaters, the power dissipation in electric stoves is regulated). I have imitated it by sweeping the load resistance RL from 100 Ω to 1 kΩ (run *DC Sweep Simulation* to see it).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFFmGF.png)</sup>

However, we see that the relationship between current and resistance is non-linear.

[image: STEP 2]

**Current-supplied load:** Of course, we can solve this problem if we supply the variable resistor with a current source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7gHGB.png)</sup>

[image: STEP 3]

### Controlled resistor

But in most cases we can neither control the source nor the load and then we are forced to insert in series an additional regulating element. In the simplest case it can be a variable resistor Rvar. Its role is to dissipate excess power (voltage VRvar) from the maximum (Vs) to the minimum (0 V). Thus, the load voltage  VL changes from the minimum (0 V) to the maximum (Vs).

Indeed, this "discarding technique" is a rather silly way of regulation ("amplification"), but all analog electronics is based on it (in pulse electronics, they do it smarter).

**Floating load:** If Rvar is grounded, the load RL will be "floating" which creates problems when cascading the amplifier stages (the input of the next stage will be grounded).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGnPfm.png)</sup>

The other trouble is that the load voltage VL depends non-linearly on the varying resistance Rvar.

[image: STEP 4]

**Grounded load:** But we easily guess to apply a little trick - *instead of the voltage across the load, take its complement to the supply voltage*. This means to replace the floating load with a constant resistor R, and to connect the grounded load in parallel with the variable resistor. Note that it has to have high resistance (in the schematic below, the voltmeter Vout serves as such a "voltage load").

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj78Sp.png)</sup>

The graph is vertically flipped (the "amplifier stage" is inverting).

[image: STEP 5]

### Controlled current source

So far, we have manually controlled the resistance of the regulating element to mimic an amplifier. In a real amplifier, however, this must be done by the input voltage. So we need *voltage-controlled resistors*.

For some reason beyond my understanding, electronic regulating elements (transistors, tubes, etc.) behave like non-linear current-stabilizing "resistors", and their IV (output) curve is an almost horizontal line what is the curve of a current source. That is why they model transistors as current sources even though they do not produce but consume power. Let's take such an "ideal transistor" (VCCS) from the CircuitLab library to make a real voltage amplifier.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0S3Hh.png)</sup>

As you can see, its transfer characteristic is linear.

[image: STEP 6]

### Unbiased transistor

Now it remains only to replace the "ideal" transistor with a real one (Q) to get a real amplifier. I have adjusted the input voltage Vin applied to the base-emitter junction so that to set the output voltage Vout equal to half of the supply voltage. You can change it carefully (because the current vigorously changes) by opening the Vin *parameters* window and setting the desired value.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQKXK3.png)</sup>

When sweeping Vin, we see something unpleasant - the amplifier characteristic is non-linear. What is even more unpleasant is that it does not start from 0 V, but somewhere from 600 mV.

[image: STEP 7]

### Biased transistor

**Input "lifting":** So we have to somehow jump over the dead zone of several hundred mV at the beginning. Practically this means adding a *bias voltage* to the input voltage. The simplest way to do it in the conceptual schematic below, is by connecting a constant voltage source Vbias1 in series with the input source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkyzXn.png)</sup>

As a result, when sweeping Vin from -10 mV to 10 mV, it appears "lifted" with 641.5 mV at the base.

**Output "lowering":** The next thing we need to do is to drop the output (collector) voltage by inserting a 5 V bias voltage source Vbias2 between the output and the load.

As a result, when sweeping Vin from -10 mV to 10 mV, the collector voltage appears "lowered" with 5 V at the load and wiggles around ground.

[image: STEP 8]

### Negative feedback

The time has come to introduce the greatest (and not only circuit) concept called by the prosaic name *negative feedback* (in the past, it was called by the more figurative name "emitter degeneration").

**Activated:** To implement it, we only need to insert a resistor Re between the emitter and ground. Thus, we force the transistor to copy the input voltage across this resistor, and the voltage VRc across the collector resistor Rc is proportional to VRe and accordingly, to Vin. As a result, VRc/Vin = Rc/Re.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjXlPW.png)</sup>

The gain decreases but becomes stable; linearity is improved.

[image: STEP 9]

**Deactivated:** The trick above was that the emitter voltage was not constant but was "moving" along with the input voltage. If we fix it, the "magic" of negative feedback will disappear, and the circuit will revert back to schematic 8. We can test it by measuring VRe and connecting a constant voltage source of the same voltage in parallel with Re.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8VNCX.png)</sup>

Gain increases and linearity worsens.

[image: STEP 10]

So the conclusion is: if we want a low but stable gain, we disconnect Ve; if we want high gain, we connect it. We will use this trick in the AC amplifier below.

### AC amplifier

**Circuit diagram:** In real circuits it is not convenient to use (floating) voltage sources; we can replace them with capacitors. We just need to provide circuits for charging/discharging them - C1 from the voltage divider R1-R2 through the input source (1 kHz sine), and C2 from the output through the load RL.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffulEq.png)</sup>

**Operation:** The behavior of the circuit already depends on the frequency of the input signal - when it is low, it is represented by schematic 9; when the frequency is high - by schematic 10. Thus we provide stability for the DC mode and amplification for the AC mode.

The previous stages were DC amplifiers. Their behaviour did not depend on time, and therefore we examined them with *DC Sweep Simulation*.

This stage is an AC amplifier whose behavior depends on time (frequency). So we have to explore it through the *Time-Domain Simulation*.

[image: STEP 11]

## Why not both voltage and power amplification?

From your comments I see that "you want to connect a 1 watt speaker". This means a low-resistance (e.g., 8 Ω) load that will consume significant current. At the same time, you also want significant voltage gain.  Unfortunately, it turns out that both are difficult to achieve at the same time, and they connect (cascade) two amplifier stages one after the other - a *voltage amplifier* followed by a *power amplifier* (buffer). Why?

**Current-driven load:** The problem is that your load (no matter floating or grounded) is connected to the collector of the transistor which acts as a current source creating a voltage drop across the load. So to get significant voltage gain, the load must be high resistance but it is not. It turns out that this stage alone won't do it.

**Voltage-driven load:** If you connect your load to the emitter of the transistor (emitter follower), there will be enough current but no voltage gain because this stage just copies the input voltage.

Comment: @Marcus Marchese, I roughly animated your schematic. I want to ask you if you understand it (what each element is for). If not, are you willing to understand it or just interested in making it work?

Comment: I dont understand the graph or what is attached to the output. I am intrested in understanding. I have been trying to build a CE amplifier with a voltage divider method of biasing for a couple months and can't figure out how to.

Comment: @Marcus Marchese, Thanks for the clarification. What I can do for you is to tell you practically what the idea of ​​all this is, starting from the very beginning, building the circuit step-by-step and explaining how to explore it. It would be great if we could do it like in life together, discussing each step, but  site policy requires this to be done at once which takes time. Therefore, my request is that you wait for me a day or two so that I can calmly create my story;  it is during this time that you will gain impressions from the rest of the answers. Thanks.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist I bet the load Rl does not match a 1W speaker.

Comment: @Justme, Thanks for the response. Of course, I know it. I just added some reasonable load to close the path for charging/discharging the C2 current. It is obvious that this is a voltage amplifier stage that need to be cascaded by a power amplifier stage. I have focused on the former.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist that would be amazing. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Marcus Marchese, I have finished my "Christmas circuit tale" :-) The subject is extensive and there is no room for full explanations here. I will be happy to answer any further questions you may have.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation I have been busy with school but I will defiantly be able to read it Thursday night. This is a very big help and I am very thankful

Comment: @Circuitfantasist I want to thank you again for putting in the time to write the Christmas tale. I just read it and it made me realize how much I don't know and how much there is for me to learn. I do have one question if I use a voltage amplifier P=VI so if the voltage increases wouldn't the power increase as well?

Comment: @Marcus Marchese, you are welcome. My answer is: if it is a true amplifier (transistor stage), yes. If it is just a transformer, the power will stay the same. See also [my recent answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/694735/can-we-replace-transformer-instead-of-transistor-for-some-particular-cases#694740).

Comment: @Circuitfantasist so in a voltage amplifier the voltage increases but the power will stay the same, then you drive the higher voltage signal into a power amplifier? So you need a higher voltage input signal for a power amplifier to properly work?

Comment: @Marcus Marchese, Yes, this is exactly the "philosophy" of amplifier construction: First we get a high intermediate voltage by passing a current (proportional to the input voltage) through a high resistance; then we make a powerful copy of that voltage and apply it to a low-resistance load to get a high current. The result is *high voltage* x *high current* = *high power*. I am glad you appreciate the role of ideas in understanding circuits.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of very high gain caused by Rc/re ratio. Removing Ce simplifies gain equation to Rc/Re, stabilizing gain by making it dependent only on external resistors rather than internal transistor resistance.

Comment: Welcome to SE EE! Good answer... By the way, what is "re" and what "internal transistor resistance"? Are they something real?

Comment: When I remove Ce the sound output is very quiet

Comment: @Marcus M. With Ce the gain is G=-gmRc=-Rc/re (re is an abbreviation for 1/gm - it is NOT a real resistance!). Withot Ce you have signal feeedback and the gain is much smaller: A=-gmRc/(1+gmRe).

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the problem of overdriving the amplifier you also have the problem of overloading the amplifier.

In a comment you state that you are connecting the amplifier to a 1 W speaker. Generally a speaker like this will have an impedance somewhere between 4\$\Omega\$ and 32\$\Omega\$. Your amplifier will not be able to drive this efficiently as it has a much higher output impedance, roughly \$R_C\$, 1200\$\Omega\$ (in simulation I get 1.13k).

So how much voltage does that allow the speaker to get? The load forms a voltage divider with the output impedance, imagine your 9 V supply connected to 1200\$\Omega\$ in series with say 16\$\Omega\$. The voltage across the 16\$\Omega\$ would be:
$$
9V\times \frac{16\Omega}{1200\Omega+16\Omega} = 118mV
$$
which gives you less than a milliwatt of power.

You can see this in the AC load line, in the first image the load is 100k and the AC load line (green) extends above and below the Q point quite a bit.
[image: Amplifier bias light load]

In the second image with a 16\$\Omega\$ load the AC load line barely gets above the Q point, there's no room for the voltage to swing very far.
[image: Amplifier bias high load]

So even if you solve the overdrive problem by reducing the gain (removing emitter bypass cap) or attenuating the input signal you're still not going to get a useful output into a typical speaker. A low impedance speaker needs to be driven by an amp with a low impedance output, typically emitter followers (common collector) in a push-pull arrangement. A common emitter amplifier such as this is meant to provide voltage gain into a high impedance load.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Is there a website or a book or a youtube video that explains how to come up with the correct values for the resistors and capacitors that you know of. Because I have been trying to learn how to build an amplifier for months and can't figure it out.

Comment: @MarcusMarchese There are lots of books and websites and videos explaining it, shouldn't be hard to find some. You have to understand that there are different types of amplifiers though, for audio there are voltage amplifiers, such as the one you're asking about, and there are power amplifiers. The voltage amplifier would be used to amplify a low level signal to get enough voltage to drive a power amplifier which then drives the speaker. Google Class A/B amplifier circuit, that should get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you I will defiantly do more research