# Can we replace transformer instead of transistor for some particular cases?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, transformer, common-base, constant-power

In a transformer, the alternating current and voltage is transformed in the secondary coil by keeping the power constant.
When we are dealing with AC, suppose that we want to amplify the voltage levels of a signal. For this purpose I use a common base NPN transistor. For CB transistor, input impedance is low and output impedance is high due to which the voltage at the output is amplified.

But the current gain factor lies between 0.95 - 0.98. Which indicates that the current at output port is low compared to current at input port.

So, the power is roughly constant as at output port voltage increases but current decreases.

The working of transistor and transformer being same in this case. Then what is the advantage of a transistor?

Comment: Welcome to SE EE! I applaud your efforts to unravel the idea behind this "mystical" CB configuration. Only to note that "at output port voltage increases" but the current does not significantly decrease; it stays (almost) the same. So the power is not "roughly constant"; it is higher, and there is amplification.

Comment: Another inappropriately closed interesting question... There is nothing vague here - the OP is quite rightly asking what the difference is between a transformer and a transistor.  The answer to this question reveals the philosophy of amplification. Rather, the question could be closed because it has already been asked (if a similar question is found), but not because it is not clear...

Comment: Are you missing the fact that the transformer just works with the power at its input whereas the amplifier works with the signal power at its input **plus** an additional power source (battery or mains) and this is where the power amplification comes from?

Answer (score 4):

I will try to explain it to you simply without using the usual verbal clichés.

## Step-up transformer

The transformer takes all the power it applies to the load from the input source. That is why the power consumed in the output part is equal to the power "produced" in the input part, and if we keep the output power constant, the input power will be also constant. Let's see it in the arrangement below where an AC input voltage source supplies a resistor load through a transformer.

### Voltage "follower"

**N = 1:** Let's first set the transformer ratio equal to 1, i.e., to make a "voltage follower".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzbmeS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this example, 1 V input voltage is transferred and applied across 100 Ω load resistance thus creating 10 mA load current and 10 mW power dissipated. This power is produced by the input source, so the same 10 mA input current flows.

[image: STEP 1a]

[image: STEP 1b]

### Voltage "amplifier"

**N = 10:** Now let's increase the transformer ratio up to 10. The output voltage is increased ten times (10 V) so it creates ten times higher load current (100 mA) and accordingly, a hundred times more power dissipated (1 W). But this power requires ten times higher input current (1 A).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3Zccm.png)</sup>

[image: STEP 2a]

[image: STEP 2b]

**N = 100:** The conclusion is that you can use a step-up transformer to increase many times (multiply, "amplify) an AC voltage, but you have to proportionally increase the load resistance so as not to overload the input voltage source. Shortly, it works in the case of high resistance loads.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXZkfx.png)</sup>

[image: STEP 3a]

[image: STEP 3b]

## CB amplifier

In a true amplifier, e.g., a common-base (CB) amplifier stage, an additional voltage source Vcc supplies the load; the input voltage Vin only controls this process through a regulating element (transistor).

**Vin = 1 V:** In the example below, 1 V input voltage causes 5 V to be applied to a 10 kΩ load in the collector circuit. As a result, 2.5 mW is dissipated into the load. You can see that I have used a little trick - to simplify the schematic, instead of a special 10 kΩ collector resistor, I have increased the ammeter internal resistance to 10 kΩ.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flWa8q.png)</sup>

**Vin = 0.99 V:** It is enough to reduce the input voltage by only 10 mV, and the power on the load increases to 5 mW. Notice that the current (common to the source and load) hardly changes, but the load voltage changes significantly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f04oPS.png)</sup>

Comment: To paraphrase: a transformer can step up voltage but not power; a transistor in common-base configuration can give a large voltage gain and small current attenuation, so there is a significant power gain.